# jQuery load more news from database to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, jsp

Before telling you my question, Hava a look into this example: ***[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/)***

Now, I'm trying to use the same example as shown but I'm fetching my data from Database using list. But as i run, It shows Two stories and if i click to show load more that news. Nothing happens. I get stuck over there. I'm trying to resolve that issues from ***12 hours***.

Please help me out!!

Have a look into my source codes:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title...</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                size_li = $("#myList li").size();
                x=3;
                $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
                $('#loadMore').click(function () {
                    x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
                    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
                });
            });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<%
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/news", "root", "1234");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from main_news order by news_id desc");
            while(rs.next()){
                String my_news=rs.getString("my_news");
    %>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<section>

<ul id="myList">
    <li>
<!-- Here, would be my news.... -->
    <%=my_news %>
    </li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
<%
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div><br>


</body>
</html>
```

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

Comment: can you provide results after jsp compilation here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to jquery logic you are counting $("#myList li").size() which is according to yours code is 1. so when you are doing  clicking on loadmore its check if logic in and find x size is more than size_li so its not doing anything.

Solution:you can use modify code

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < my_news.size(); i++) { %>
   <li>      
       <%=my_news[i] %>
   </li>
   <%{ %>
```

you can use jslt tags also to write code.